# Rails ActiveRecord: Select Posts WITHOUT comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a a Comments table and a Posts table, where a Post has many comments and a comment belongs to a post (i.e. it has a post_id in the table).

How can I efficiently select the last ten Posts that DO NOT have comments.
I can't seem to accomplish this without first selecting all the posts and checking each for a 0 comment count.

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Nathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) to the `Comment` model and a couple of [named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) to the `Post` model. Something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  named_scope :recent, :limit => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC'
  named_scope :uncommented, :conditions => { :comments_count => 0 }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

If you're using Rails 3 then the named scope syntax is a little different:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  scope :recent, limit(10).order('posts.created_at DESC')
  scope :uncommented, where(:comments_count => 0)
end
```

Now you can find posts without any comments by chaining the named scopes together:

```
@uncommented = Post.recent.uncommented
```

If you wanted to get all the posts without any comments (i.e. not just the ten most recent posts), then it would be:

```
@uncommented = Post.uncommented
```

—You may have noticed that in the Rails 3 example I included the `posts` table name in the `:recent` scope. This is a good practice to get in to so that you avoid ambiguous column names in SQL queries if two tables have the same column name. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) explains more.

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
Post.find(:all, :include => :comments, :conditions => "comments.id is null", :limit => 10, :order => "created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `comments_count` column to your posts table and let the migration update the counters. From now on Rails will automagically update your counter if you supply `:counter_cache => true` on the association. It is very easy to select the last 10 posts now:

```
Post.find_all_by_comments_count 0, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10
```

Documentation link: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001318

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a condition somehow like this:

```
:conditions => '(SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id = #{id}) = 0'
```

I'm not an expert in SQL so maybe there's something like an EMPTY keyword or so.

Comment: for that matter you should have double quotes in order for #{id} to be substituted

Comment: Better don't do that anyway as it may open your code to SQL injection. Do this :conditions => ['(SELECT ... WHERE post_id = ?) = 0', id]

Comment: @hurikhan77: You’re right. I was referring to a ActiveRecord relation where it would be ok to do as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a left outer join:

```
Post.all :joins => "left outer join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id", :conditions => "comments.id is null", :limit => 10, :order => 'created at desc'
```

This link should help you understand the different types of SQL joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.id is null")